# Cannot install any packages after update. Additional packages don't get included

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, skype

There was a software update on 16.04 and after installing updates, I can't install any new packages easily. It doesn't list out additional packages required anymore. For example:

```
 apt-get install skype
      The following packages have unmet dependencies:
       skype : Depends: skype-bin
 apt-get install skype skype-bin
      The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
 apt-get install skype skype-bin libqtgui4:i386
      The following packages have unmet dependencies:
      libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed

 You get it....
```

In the past, when I tried `sudo apt-get install skype`  it would list additional packages.

And Now Aptitude: (sometimes aptitude works fine, it downloads all needed)

```
 sudo aptitude install skype
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libaudio2:i386{a} libdbusmenu-qt2:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} libmng2:i386{a} 
   libmysqlclient20:i386{a} libqt4-dbus:i386{a} libqt4-declarative:i386{a} 
   libqt4-network:i386{a} libqt4-opengl:i386{a} libqt4-script:i386{a} 
   libqt4-sql:i386{a} libqt4-sql-mysql:i386{a} libqt4-xml:i386{a} 
   libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386{a} libqtcore4:i386{a} libqtdbus4:i386{a} 
   libqtgui4:i386{a} libqtwebkit4:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} lbuuid1:i386{ab} 
   libxss1:i386{a} libxt6:i386{a} libxv1:i386{a} mysql-common{a} 
   qt-at-spi:i386{a} skype skype-bin:i386{a} sni-qt:i386{a} 
 0 packages upgraded, 28 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
 Need to get 41.9 MB/42.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 124 MB will be used.
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3 is to be installed.
  libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1 is installed.
 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)      libaudio2:i386 [Not Installed]                     
 2)      libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 [Not Installed]               
 3)      libqt4-declarative:i386 [Not Installed]            
 4)      libqt4-opengl:i386 [Not Installed]                 
 5)      libqtgui4:i386 [Not Installed]                     
 6)      libqtwebkit4:i386 [Not Installed]                  
 7)      libsm6:i386 [Not Installed]                        
 8)      libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                      
 9)      libxt6:i386 [Not Installed]                        
 10)     qt-at-spi:i386 [Not Installed]                     
 11)     skype [Not Installed]                              
 12)     skype-bin:i386 [Not Installed]                     
 13)     sni-qt:i386 [Not Installed]                        

  Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
 14)     skype-bin:i386 recommends sni-qt:i386              


 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
 No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
 Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

**No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.** WHAT?? WHY?

OKAY now no instead of Y and then downgrade a package.

```
 Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
 The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Downgrade the following packages:                               
 1)     libuuid1 [2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 2.27.1-6ubuntu3 (xenial)]
```

Now it works, after it downgrades it downloads everything.

Update: I purged Skype. It seems like `sudo apt-get install skype -f` works too. Shouldn't it by default recommend/suggested package as usual?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: -f works. But not sure if that's because after downgrading libuuid1. Updated the question with that info. I purged skype and tried -f.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to make sure you have the latest version of all packages.

Comment: hmm no. I run apt update all the time. apt upgrade breaks  some things so I never run that and it's not necessary in this case. Rather a downgrade fixed aptitude and force fixed apt

Comment: Never run `apt upgrade`??? Then you ask for trouble when installing new packages, as in this case.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f libqtgui4:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386`?

Comment: @Gunnar I don't need newer versions on packages to break existing ones, mostly on 3 of my desktops upgrade breaks something. I shouldn't have installed latest update at all but I gave it a shot and just like always it broke apt (or not?) I have no idea what the issue is. I expected something that needs to be changed so it gives me suggestions like before, the issue doesn't sound like it needed upgrade,  you should have suggested apt downgrade instead, jk or something get rid of latest updates.  Check the updated post, downgrading fixed aptitude.  force fixes apt

Comment: @JohnDoe, Would you split the solution to an answer then accept it. It is hard to search for it as it is not in Ask Ubuntu Q&A format.